# How to get rid of from database error in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have created database setup model with dbforge and also called it via controller for setting database. but problem is when i run url from localhost, it gives error with database error calling **"Unknown database 'loginproject'"**. noted that i have set database in config> database.php ***'database' => 'loginproject',***. if i will remove it, it will not show error. but i want to stay it there, because later it will be need in project. how to set it with staying there for database setup. my code is below.

**Welcome.php- controller:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this-> home();
    }


    public function home()
    {

        $data['title'] = 'This is title';

        $this -> load -> model('setup_model');

        $this -> setup_model -> createDatabase();

        $this -> load -> view('welcome_message');


    }

}
```

**Setup_model.php- Model:**

```
<?php

class setup_model extends CI_Model

{

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function createDatabase()

    {

        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->dbforge();

 if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists('loginproject'))
 {

    $this->dbforge->create_database('loginproject');

    $this->db->query('use loginproject');


        $fields = array(

            'user_id' => array(

                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true

            ),

            'username' => array(

                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 230,

            ),

             'email' => array(

                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 250,
            ),

            'password' => array(

             'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255,
            ),


            'created_date' => array(

             'type' => 'date',

            ),

            'phone' => array(

             'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255,
            ),



        );


         $this -> dbforge -> add_field($fields);

         $this -> dbforge -> add_key('user_id', true);

         $this -> dbforge -> create_table('users');


         echo "Setup Done Succesfully";

  }



    }



}
```

Comment: are you added database library in autoload `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: it has been added. though it is is giving error

Answer (score 0):

create your database manually and connect config/database.php
then change following in your **createDatabase()**

```
public function createDatabase(){
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->dbforge();
        if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists('loginproject'))
        {
        $this->dbforge->create_database('loginproject');
        }
        $this->db->query('use loginproject');
        $fields = array(
        'user_id' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'constraint' => 11,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'auto_increment' => true
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 230,
        ),
         'email' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 250,
        ),
        'password' => array(
         'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 255,
        ),
        'created_date' => array(
         'type' => 'date',
        ),
        'phone' => array(
         'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 255,
        ),
        );
        $this -> dbforge -> add_field($fields);
        $this -> dbforge -> add_key('user_id', true);
        $this -> dbforge -> create_table('users');
        echo "Setup Done Succesfully";
}
```

Comment: what you have changed?

Comment: the only closing of if condition if the database already exists

Comment: no, it will check database exist or not, then also will be create table also, table will be created once with this condition